# Перебор массива с отрицательными ключами

Tags: javascript

Есть массив (объект), который содержит положительные и отрицательные ключи. Но пытаясь перебрать его, судя по всему, он никак не воспринимает отрицательные ключи (перебор идет от 0) и выдает ошибку. Что в этом случае можно сделать?

```
mr = {
"0": {
 title: "qwe"
},
"-1": {
 title: "qwe2"
},
"-2": {
 title: "qwe3"
}
};
Object.keys(mr)
.map(function(file, index) {
    console.log(mr[index]["title"]);
});
```

Comment: замените `index` на `file`

Comment: Прошу обратить внимание что у вас ключи не числа а строки!!!

Comment: @ZMS, как ни странно, но ключи **всегда** строки

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В данном случае неверно получаются значения: `Object.keys(mr)` возвращает массив **ключей**, то есть в коллбэке для функции `map` первый параметр стоило назвать `key` для отражения смысла.

```
Object.keys(mr)
    .map(function(key, index) {
```

Теперь сразу видно, что `index` в данном случае это номер ключа в массиве, а не сам ключ.

Для получения значения из объекта, надо было использовать ключ.

```js
mr = {
  "0": {
    title: "qwe"
  },
  "-1": {
    title: "qwe2"
  },
  "-2": {
    title: "qwe3"
  }
};
Object.keys(mr) // ["0", "-1", "-2"]
  .map(function(key, index) {
    console.log(mr[key]["title"]);
  });
```

Comment: Буду на твоих ответах (как `единственного профессионала`) изучать JS